# Enable Spanish tick inside equation environment

Tags: equations, accents

How can I enable an accented letter, like in Spanish, inside an `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` environment like below? It's just curiosity.

```
\begin{equation*}
    P   :   Presión
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: You mean that contain text, for example word `Presión` ? Try `\begin{equation*}
    P   :   \text{ Presión}
\end{equation*}`. For this you nead to use package `amsmath` or `mathtools`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want text inside an equation, use `\text` (or `\textit` if you want italics):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
P\text{: Presión}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can put any text inside a math environment (equations, $$ ... $$, etc) using the `\text{}` option. For example, the code below produces this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
P = \frac{F}{A}, \quad \text{donde P: Presión, F: Fuerza, A: Área}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

As this enables a text environment, you can adjust the text as you like (size, bold, italicts, etc). Notice that this requires the `inputenc` and `amsmath` packages.

Alternatively, you can use the more cumbersome, brute force, and less elegant method of math accents, by using the `\acute{}` command. For example, the code below produces this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*
P = \frac{F}{A}, \quad \text{donde} \quad P: presi\acute{o}n, \quad F: Fuerza, \quad A: \acute{A}rea
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Notice that by default the math environment is in italics.

Saludos! ;)

Comment: Ty luchonacho :D

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: Words should be typeset exactly like “donde”, that is `\text{Presión}`.

Comment: Good point. Any reason behind the "should"?

Comment: @luchonacho `$d = 3, donde P es presi\acute{o}n$` means `d = 3, d × o × n × d × e × P × e × s × p × r × e × s × i × ó × n`. That is, consecutive letters means multiplication in math mode. In addition, `\text` makes non-italic text.

Comment: I see the point, and updated the answer. But, besides the italics bit, it is a very technical point.

Comment: The answer is now wrong for another reason: the variables P, F and A should be in math mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the package `lmodern`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    P : Presión, Pressão, Pressure
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    V_{méd} = \frac{\Delta S}{\Delta t}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    A_{á} = E_{é} + I_{í} + O_{ó} + U_{ú}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    Ã = É + Ì + Ô + Ü
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]